# How to set vue3-chartjs fixed height?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, height, vuejs3, fixed

I'm using Vue3 wrapper for ChartJS [JT-McC/vue3-chartjs - GitHub](https://github.com/J-T-McC/vue3-chartjs) and
I want to make a fixed height bar chart .

This is the code :

```
<template>
  <h2>Bar Chart</h2>
  <div style="height: 700px">
    <vue3-chart-js v-bind="{ ...barChart }" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue3ChartJs from "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Vue3ChartJs,
  },
  setup() {
    const barChart = {
      type: "bar",
      options: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: "top",
          },
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
            ticks: {
              callback: function (value) {
                return `${value}%`;
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      data: {
        labels: ["VueJs", "EmberJs", "ReactJs", "AngularJs"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "My First Dataset",
            backgroundColor: ["#1abc9c", "#f1c40f", "#2980b9", "#34495e"],
            data: [40, 20, 50, 10],
          },
          {
            label: "My Second Dataset",
            backgroundColor: ["#2ecc71", "#e67e22", "#9b59b6", "#bdc3c7"],
            data: [-40, -20, -10, -10],
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    return {
      barChart,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I already try to set the height to 700px

```
  <div style="height: 700px">
    <vue3-chart-js v-bind="{ ...barChart }" />
  </div>
```

But it's not working, chart height doesn't change at all.

This is the demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-set-chart-js-fixed-height-1oxsb?file=/src/App.vue)

Is possible to set fixed height in chart.js?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
<vue3-chart-js v-bind="{ ...barChart }" :height="700"/>
```